# fund transfer in stripe from admin to connected accounts

Tags: php, stripe-connect

I am working on Integration of Stripe in php.

Scenario is: customers are paying money to a admin's stripe account and after some days admin want to pay to his other connected account.

What i have done So far is:

1. Customers payment is working fine.
2. Created Connected accounts.
3. Verified Connected accounts.

   \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_rdCVucE0VS6dK729JQx3UeAJ');

   ```
    \Stripe\Account::create(
       array(
           "country" => "US",
           "managed" => true,

           "external_account" => array(
               "object" => "card",
               "country" => "US",
               "currency" => "usd",
               "number" => "4000000000000077",
               ),
           )
       );

   /*------------------------------Update User------------------*/
   $account = \Stripe\Account::retrieve('acct_18zEaLF4JdCk8535');
   $account->legal_entity->first_name = "raghvendra";
   $account->legal_entity->last_name = "Singh";
   $account->legal_entity->dob->day = 22;
   $account->legal_entity->dob->month = 8;
   $account->legal_entity->dob->year = 1994;
   $account->legal_entity->type = 'individual';
   $account->tos_acceptance->date = time();
   $account->tos_acceptance->ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
   $account->legal_entity->ssn_last_4 = '8547';
   $account->legal_entity->address->line1 = 'aa';
   $account->legal_entity->address->city= 'bb';
   $account->legal_entity->address->postal_code = '12345';
   $account->legal_entity->address->state = 'st';
   $account->legal_entity->personal_id_number='123458547';

   $account->legal_entity->additional_owners = array(
       array('first_name' => 'Bob', 'last_name' => 'Smith'),
       array('first_name' => 'Jane', 'last_name' => 'Doe')
       );

   $count = count($account->legal_entity->additional_owners);
   $account->legal_entity->additional_owners[$count] = array(
       'first_name' => 'Andrew',
       'last_name' => 'Jackson'
       );

   $account->legal_entity->additional_owners = null;

   /*------------------------------Verify user-----------------------------*/

   $file = \Stripe\FileUpload::create(
       array(
           "purpose" => "identity_document",
           "file" => fopen(public_path().'/img/1.jpg', 'r')
           ),
       array("stripe_account" => 'acct_18zEaLF4JdCk8535')
       );
   $img_id = $file->id;
   $account = \Stripe\Account::retrieve('acct_18zEaLF4JdCk8535');
   $account->legal_entity->verification->document = $img_id;
   $account->save();
   ```

   }

**Now**
Suppose $100 is in Admin Account and admin wants to transfer $50 to his one of Account.

For transfer fund, I am using

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_rdCVucE0VS6dK729JQx3UeAJ');

\Stripe\Transfer::create(array(
    "amount" => 400,
    "currency" => "usd",
    "destination" => "acct_18zEaLF4JdCk8535",
    "description" => "Transfer for test@example.com"
    ));
```

**Is this possible ?** Please help me to

Comment: have you got the solution of this problem of yours ?

Comment: yes.i was right.!

Comment: Can you let me know what have you done to get that done? I also have the same flow in my app.

Comment: actually my code was right but i was using older stripe api at that time so i was not able to transfer the payment...after updating to latest api,above  code  is fine.. !

Answer (score 0):

```
`\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_rdCVucE0VS6dK729JQx3UeAJ');`

`\Stripe\Transfer::create(array(
    "amount" => 400,
    "currency" => "usd",
    "destination" => "acct_18zEaLF4JdCk8535",
    "description" => "Transfer for test@example.com"
    ));
`
After above process u get a amount in your stripe external account. 
Now u want transfer it in your bank account 
So use a payout for that like below.

`$data = ["amount" => 400, "currency" => 'USD'];
\Stripe\Payout::create($data, ["stripe_account" => acct_18zEaLF4JdCk8535];`

Now its done
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.